# PnP Provisioning: What is the ControlId good for?

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp, pnp-provision, pnp-provisioning

I'm importing PnP templates for SharePoint Online using the latest [PnP Provisioning Engine](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/introducing-the-pnp-provisioning-engine). The templates include client side pages with web parts that each got a [`ControlId`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/officedevpnp.core.framework.provisioning.model.canvascontrol.controlid?view=sharepoint-pnpcoreol-3.2.1810) property.

For well-known official web parts like the text web part or the news web part those `ControlId`s seem to be constant across sites.

[image]

Now I am also creating and manipulating PnP templates programmatically. Here's the question: can the `ControlId` be a random GUID for each web part, even official ones? Or does it have to have the well-known GUID for official web parts? How important is getting this ID right?

Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: For official web parts, I would imagine this needs to remain the same. For identifying different web parts on a page, rather than type, you might want to look at the JSON control data and specifically the instance ID.

Comment: @CallumCrowley What has me wondering is the documentation of the ControlId property: "Defines the Instance Id for Canvas Control of a Client-side Page."

Comment: That's odd, in the JSON control data, there is usually an instance ID which is different from the canvas control ID.

Comment: There is a merry mixing of `ControlId`, `InstanceId`, and `WebPartId` going on in the PnP Framework: https://github.com/pnp/pnpframework/blob/121c69280db556259e046b6d5f42174c00701a5e/src/lib/PnP.Framework/Provisioning/ObjectHandlers/Utilities/ClientSidePageContentsHelper.cs#L266 https://github.com/pnp/pnpframework/blob/121c69280db556259e046b6d5f42174c00701a5e/src/lib/PnP.Framework/Provisioning/ObjectHandlers/Utilities/ClientSidePageContentsHelper.cs#L287